# Can i run a single job to trigger multiple release pipelines in Azure Devops

Tags: deployment, tags, release

Can i run a single job to trigger multiple release pipelines in Azure Devops. We have multiple microservices which are being built and deployed separately that are independent of each other but the business ask now is to treat them as a release and deploy so wondering how that can be achieved off a release tag(1.x.x)which gets tagged for every release run.

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing for the app I work on. We wrote a PowerShell script to kick off the releases utilizing the DevOps Rest API. The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.

You basically pass in a list of Release DefinitionIds and then set the status of the latest Release to "inProgress" to start it.

If you want to target a specific release, you can use the `searchText` query parameter to find a release by the name. We created a variable group with the names of the releases in it and use that to target them.